# Write image to folder

Tags: python

I am trying to save a scrapped image to a different folder than the present.

```
├── heatmaps
├── league
├── player
└── players_data.py
```

This is my current working directory tree.

```
base64_image_away = driver.execute_script(
        "return document.querySelector('.canvas-container[data-field=away] canvas').toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);")

    output_image_away = base64.b64decode(base64_image_away)

    with open("image" + "_" + away_team + ".png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(output_image_away)
```

I tried to change add `../heatmaps/` on the open line but it didn't work.
Any solution for this? And if possible something to create the folder if it does not exist.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have two options,

1.change your current dir using,

```
os.chdir("../heatmaps/")
```

2.Use absolute path like,

```
/Users/nawarkhede/Desktop
```

Example:

Using `os.chdir`

```
In [1]: pwd
Out[1]: u'/Users/nawarkhede/projects/notifier'

In [2]: with open('samlpe.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     f.write('HI')
   ...:

In [3]: ls
db.sqlite3  manage.py*  notifier/   samlpe.txt  templates/

In [4]: import os

In [5]: os.chdir("/Users/nawarkhede/Desktop/") . # Changing directory

In [6]: with open('samlpe1.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     f.write('HI')
   ...:
   ...:

In [7]: pwd
Out[7]: u'/Users/nawarkhede/Desktop'

In [8]: ls
samlpe1.txt


In [9]:
```